# OwlCarousel2 shows blank slides while every other HTML tags are showing up fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel-2

I have been trying to fix it out but haven't got any solution that may help. I have been following the official installation docs.
My Owlcarousel2 version is 2.3.4, I have tried other versions, all are same. OwlCarousel old is working fine but Owlcarousel2 is not.
here is my HTML

```
<html>
<head>

<link href="OwlCarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="OwlCarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})

</script>

<style>#owl-demo .item {
    border:solid;
  margin: 3px;
}
</style>

</head>

</html>
<body>
    <h1>Owl</h1>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="images/FEATURE1.PNG"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/FEATURE2.PNG"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/FEATURE3.PNG"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/FEATURE4.PNG"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/FEATURE5.PNG"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/FEATURE6.PNG"></div>

</div>

<h1>Owl</h1>

<script src="OwlCarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="OwlCarousel/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

`<h1>Owl</h1>`are showing up but data of class `.owl-carousel` is invisible

Comment: Check your browser console, it should tell you that `$` is not defined. You need to embed the jQuery script _before_ you start using $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sort out the main reason. It was just the placing order of script.
it is clear that we should use `jquery.js` and `owl-carousel.js` before your javascript to initialize your carousel.

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="owl/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="owl/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<style>

.item{
border:solid;
}
</style>
</head>

</html>
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h1>Owl</h1>
    <hr/>


<div class="row" >
<div class="owl-carousel col-6" style="">
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>

</div>
</div>

<script src="owl/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="owl/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});

</script>

<hr/>    
<h1>Owl</h1>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have put a double`$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({..})`.

Use this instead:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
       loop:true,
       margin:10,
       nav:true,
       responsive:{
           0:{
               items:1
           },
           600:{
               items:3
           },
           1000:{
               items:5
           }
       }
   });
   });

</script>
```

Comment: it was fine. main issue I thought may be due to the placing order of scripts.Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine insted of placement of scripts. You must follow this sequence.
1: `jquery`
2:  `owl.carousel.js`
3: Then call the owlcarousal

```
    <html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="owl/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="owl/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<style>

.item{
border:solid;
}
</style>
</head>

</html>
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h1>Owl</h1>
    <hr/>

<div class="row" >
<div class="owl-carousel col-6" style="">
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>Data</h1></div>

</div>
</div>

<script src="owl/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="owl/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
       loop:true,
       margin:10,
       nav:true,
       responsive:{
           0:{
               items:1
           },
           600:{
               items:3
           },
           1000:{
               items:5
           }
       }
   });
   });

</script>

<hr/>    
<h1>Owl</h1>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the line space

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30294658)